# UnsatisfiedlinkError : undefined symbol _ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv in java (JNI)

Tags: c++, boost, linker, java-native-interface

I have created an .so file in which I am not at all using the boost library (Of course earlier I used it), but later I switched to pthreads and removed all the header files and boost .so file linking from the makefile.

The java files are getting compiled successfully. But, when I try to run using

`java -Djava.library.path=libs/ -cp build/ Send`

it gives me the following error.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/aahmed/libplxmsg-java/libs/libplxmsgjavaasyncbinder.so: /home/aahmed/libplxmsg-java/libs/libplxmsgjavaasyncbinder.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv`

I am sure that I am not using any boost related libraries or header files. Even the link for the .so file is given correctly.

### EDIT

On executing `nm` on the `.so` file which was being loaded. Small snipped of that.

`00000000002044d8 b _ZN5boost6system10errno_ecatE
00000000002044e0 b _ZN5boost6system11native_ecatE
00000000000031a0 W _ZN5boost6system12system_errorD0Ev
00000000000033a0 W _ZN5boost6system12system_errorD1Ev
0000000000003180 W _ZN5boost6system14error_categoryD0Ev
0000000000003050 W _ZN5boost6system14error_categoryD1Ev
00000000002044d0 b _ZN5boost6system14posix_categoryE
                 U _ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv
                 U _ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv
0000000000003060 W _ZN7JNIEnv_14CallVoidMethodEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDz
00000000000030f0 W _ZN7JNIEnv_9NewObjectEP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDz
                 U _ZN9__gnu_cxx18__exchange_and_addEPVii@@GLIBCXX_3.4
0000000000003240 W _ZNK5boost6system12system_error4whatEv
0000000000003030 W _ZNK5boost6system14error_category10equivalentERKNS0_10error_codeEi
0000000000002fe0 W _ZNK5boost6system14error_category10equivalentEiRKNS0_15error_conditionE
0000000000002fd0 W _ZNK5boost6system14error_category23default_error_conditionEi`

Comment: perform an `nm` on the `.so` file and verify the fact that it isn't using boost because that error message implies that it needs it.

Comment: I ran that command on the `.so` file, it was giving some boost related symbols. But, I am not at all using any boost libraries or even header files during the compilation and even during linking. What causes this error ? How to avoid it ? (Just attached a small snippet of output from executing `nm` command.)

Comment: Without a copy of the build script (makefile? bjam file?) it's just guesswork. I would recommend removing all `.so` and `.o` files and rebuild the library, checking for the boost libraries - there may be a stray file from a previous build

Comment: I m deleting all the `.o` files and `.so` files during each and every clean. You say that there is still some file which is using that boost library ?

Comment: The most simple way avoid this error is to link with `Boost.System` (`-lboost_system`).

Comment: Yes, that is what appears to be the case. You can run `nm` on each of the individual `.o` files that makes up the `.so` file in the hopes of tracking it down. Again, you need to be methodical with this - check what `.o`, `.a` files make up the `.so` - know for certain - it may be linking a library that has a boost dependency; examine each of these `.o` files individually

Comment: @IgorR. I tried linking the `-lboost_system`, but it was giving error like `libboost_system.so.1.50.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. I am giving correct path to the so file.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to create your shared library (one that is used from Java) such it is linked with boost. For example:

```
g++ -g -shared -fpic -L$(BOOST)/lib \
-lboost_system -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include \
-I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux \
your_code.c -o libyourcode.so
```

This way, your JNI code will be properly linked with boost.